# Why ls -1 /tmp/dir/ /and ls -1 /tmp/dir/* doesn't show the same result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

*ls -1 /tmp/dir/* returns:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

*ls -1 /tmp/dir/** returns:

```
/tmp/dir/file1.txt
/tmp/dir/file2.txt
```

Why there is this difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument to `ls` denotes a directory, it shows the files in the directory without a path component. If the argument is a file with a path component, it displays the path component.

In `ls -1 /tmp/dir` ls sees only the directory. Hence only the files.

`ls -1 /tmp/dir/*` is expanded by the shell to `ls -1 /tmp/dir/file1.txt /tmp/dir/file2.txt`, hence `ls` sees two files with a path component.